# Convert pdf file to single image file? (page on top of page)

Tags: image, pdf, image-processing, tiff

I was wondering if anyone knew a good way to convert a multi-page PDF file to a long image file, page on top of page. All converters I can find just give you multiple images, each one page of the PDF. But i need a single image.

Or a way to convert multiple images to one large image, with one image on top of the other.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the converters that produces multiple images and then you can append them using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) and "flag" [-append](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append):

> Basically it joins the current sequence of images in memory into a
>   column, or a row, without gaps. No form of justification such as
>   centering is (currently) provided, so images are aligned either along
>   their left, or top edges, as appropriate. The "-append" option appends
>   vertically, while the plus form "+append" appends horizontally.

Example of command:

```
convert page_A.gif page_B.gif page_C.gif page_D.gif page_E.gif \
          page_F.gif page_G.gif page_H.gif -append  appended.gif
```

Comment: Thanks! I found this answer while looking for a solution to the same basic problem. I thought I'd note that you can also use the append option with the single multi-page .pdf file, as in `convert -append source.pdf image.tif`, which doesn't require creating the individual page images first.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use imagemagick:

```
convert work.pdf work.tiff
```

Done.

E.g:

```
$ identify test.pdf 
test.pdf[0] PDF 183x275 183x275+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 32KB 0.000u 0:00.000
test.pdf[1] PDF 181x278 181x278+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 32KB 0.000u 0:00.000
test.pdf[2] PDF 178x280 178x280+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 32KB 0.000u 0:00.000
test.pdf[3] PDF 180x272 180x272+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 32KB 0.000u 0:00.000
test.pdf[4] PDF 179x274 179x274+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 32KB 0.000u 0:00.000

identify test.tiff 
test.tiff[0] TIFF 183x275 183x275+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 33.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
test.tiff[1] TIFF 181x278 181x278+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 33.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
test.tiff[2] TIFF 178x280 178x280+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 33.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
test.tiff[3] TIFF 180x272 180x272+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 33.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
test.tiff[4] TIFF 179x274 179x274+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 33.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```